# js animation is not working in mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

I have created functions given below-

```
function moveObj1(){
    left = parseInt(imgObjPurple.style.left, 10);
    moveRightDown = 300;
    if (parseInt(screen.height) + moveRightDown >= left) {
        imgObjPurple.style.left = (left + 4) + 'px';
        imgObjPurple.style.top = (parseInt(imgObjPurple.style.top) + downValue) + 'px';
        imgObjPurple.style.display = 'block';
        animate = setTimeout(function () {
            moveObj1();
       }, 15);
    }
}

function moveObj2() {
    moveRightDown = 300;
    left1 = parseInt(imgObjBlue.style.left, 10);
    if (parseInt(screen.height) + moveRightDown >= left1) {
        imgObjBlue.style.left = (left1 + 4) + 'px';
        imgObjBlue.style.top = (parseInt(imgObjBlue.style.top) + downValue) + 'px';
        imgObjBlue.style.display = 'block';
        animate = setTimeout(function () {
            moveObj2();
     }, 15);
 }
function move(){
    moveObj1();
    setTimeout(function(){
        moveObj2();
    });
}
```

and trying to call in repeated manner as -

```
move();
SetInterval(function(){
    move();
},100);
```

But its working one or two times and then objects are overlapping each other. How i fix it? Any Help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: @RayonDabre look at this- https://jsfiddle.net/5e4c36bq/2/

Comment: _So may nested function calls in interval..._

Comment: @RayonDabre so ho i achieve this?

Comment: Remove nested function call...

Comment: thanks @Rayon. It resolved.